# Can you trigger Build Now on a specific slave node with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

When I add a new slave node to Jenkins I would like to trigger a single build of a specific project on the new slave to test it. I'd like to do this without editing the configuration of that project. i.e. it would be a one shot build.

Is there an option available (either builtin or via a plugin) to run Build Now but on a specific slave node?

Comment: is it a freestyle or pipeline project?

Comment: @Amityo freestyle

Comment: if you don't mind changing the configuration each time you need it you can try - http://serverfault.com/questions/359793/tell-jenkins-to-run-a-specific-project-on-a-particular-slave-node

Comment: @Amityo as mentioned in my question I don't want to change the configuration.

Comment: if it were pipeline job i would recommend to just hit the replay button and set the `node('label-for-my-requested-node') {//block}`, but i'm not sure if it's possible for freestyle jobs...

Comment: @Amityo my ideal solution (which I don't think exists hence the question) is that you can click build now with a popup menu to select the slave node.

Comment: You can define a NodeLabel parameter for the job with some default values for nondebug use case. BuildNow wont work for you.